# calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{\cos xdx }{3 + \cos^2 x}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{\cos x dx}{3 + \cos^2 x}}$

So I said:

> $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{\cos x dx}{3 + \cos^2 x}} = I$
>
> I = $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{2\cos x dx}{3 + \cos^2 x}}$ -  $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{\cos x dx}{3 + \cos^2 x}} = ln(3 + \cos^2 x) - I $
>
> $\rightarrow 2I = \ln(3+\cos^2 x)$
>
> $\rightarrow I = \frac{\ln(3+cos^2x)}{2}, from \; 0 \; to \; \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{ln(3) - ln(4)}{2}$

But my professor tells me that is wrong. Why?

Comment: Because $\frac{d \cos^2 x}{dx} = - 2\cos x\sin x$, and not $2\cos x$. Use $t = \sin x$ as a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{2\cos x}{3+\cos^2 x}\mathrm{d}x\neq\ln(3+\cos^2x)$$

as $\dfrac{d}{dx}(3+\cos^2 x)=-2\cos x\sin x$ $(\neq  2\cos x)$

EDIT:

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{3+\cos^2 x}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\cos x}{4-\sin^2 x}\mathrm{d}x$$

Now subs. $t=\sin x$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $u=\sin x$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{3+\cos^2x}\,dx&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{3+(1-\sin^2x)}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{3+(1-u^2)}\,dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{4-u^2}\,du=\frac14\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{2-u}+\frac{1}{2+u}\right)\,du\\
&=&\frac14\left[\ln|u+2|-\ln|u-2|\right]_0^1=\frac14\ln3.
\end{eqnarray}